# Why does `<<` append to a Ruby string while `+=` does not?

Tags: ruby, string, reference

I'm working through a tutorial right now, and I'd like to understand why the following occurs:

```
original_string = "Hello, "
hi = original_string
there = "World"
hi += there
assert_equal "Hello, ", original_string

original_string = "Hello, "
hi = original_string
there = "World"
hi << there
assert_equal "Hello, World", original_string
```

Why does `+=` have no effect on `original_string`, and `<<` does?  I was absolutely certain that the second case would also equal `"Hello, "`, but that's not the case.

`hi = original string` in the first example appears to copy the value of `original_string` into `hi`, but `hi = original string` in the second example appears to set `hi` to point to the same string as `original string`.  I would guess there is some kind of implicit decision behind the scenes as to whether to copy the value or copy the reference... or something.

Answer (score 3):

`<<` on string mutates the original object while `+=` creates a copy and returns that.

See the `object_id` of the respective strings below:

```
2.1.1 :029 > original_string = "Hello, "
 => "Hello, " 
2.1.1 :030 > hi = original_string
 => "Hello, " 
2.1.1 :031 > there = "World"
 => "World" 
2.1.1 :032 > original_string.object_id
 => 70242326713680 
2.1.1 :033 > hi.object_id
 => 70242326713680 

2.1.1 :034 > hi += there
 => "Hello, World" 
2.1.1 :035 > hi.object_id
 => 70242325614780
```

Note the different `object_id` on `hi` on line 35.  Once you reset `hi` to `original_string` in your example above, and use `<<`, it modifies the same object.

Answer (score 3):

In both examples, `hi = original_string` copies the reference.

With `+=`, however, you reassign `hi` to point to a new string, even though the variable name is the same.

This is because `hi += there` expands in the interpreter to the expression `hi = hi + there`.

Before this operation, `hi` and `original string` share a reference to the same string object. Upon the `=` operation in the expanded expression, `hi` now references the newly-created string result of `hi + there`.

In the expression `hi << there`, nothing happens to change which object `hi` refers to. It refers to the same string as `original_string`, and therefore both `hi` and `original_string` reflect the change (which is of course due to the fact that they both reference the same string object).

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Ruby documentation for the String Class:

[String#+ method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-2B)

[String#<< method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-3C-3C)